# iOS7 - content overlapping during push segue from table view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7, tableview, segue

Apologies if this has been asked before. I can't find any reference to this particular problem though.

I have an app which is basically a table view nested within a navigation controller. Each item from the table segues to a fresh view (via a generic push transition), containing some content within a scrollview. I have set this all up using storyboard for ease of layout.

When you click an item in the table, the intention is for the table to slide off the screen to the left and be replaced by the content view. This works fine in iOS 6, but since testing the app on iOS 7 I've noticed the functionality is different.

In iOS 7 the content view slides into frame as normal, but the table view only slides a little way to the left - still visible behind my new content. It disappears very suddenly after half a second or so, but the effect is very jarring as it creates a momentary overlap of two views.

This is only a problem because my content views have transparent backgrounds, but this is important to maintain for the effect I want. So just to be clear, my content view slides in *over the top* of the menu, which subsequently disappears. Looks very odd.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I'd be curious to know the reason for this change and if there's a way I can fix it. Preferably by making the menu slide all the way offscreen again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

Try to add into target ViewController (that shows up after push)

`- (void)viewDidLoad {`

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

}

If all is ok you can change background to something like that

```
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenBkg.png"]];
```

ps. tableView needs to be defined as @property in your .h filw

Comment: I had this same problem and couldn't figure out the solution for the life of me. Why this is causing an overlap, I don't know, but this fixed it.

Comment: I think having a clear background is causing this overlap and setting it to white is fixing the issue as content behind white background won't be visible.